# Getting an error while trying to return a pointer to struct that is forward declared in a header file

Tags: c, pointers

In one of the header file, I am working with, there is a forward declaration of a structure which reads:

```
typedef struct my_server_t my_server_t;
```

and of a function which reads:

```
my_server_t *server_create();
```

Now in the `.c` file, I am trying to implement `server_create` function. This is what I am doing:

```
my_server_t* server_create(){
    struct server {
        unsigned short port;
        int pending_connections_allowed;
    } server_t;
    return (gfserver_t *)server_t;
}
```

But as I try to compile the `.c` code, I get an error saying:

```
error: operand of type 'struct server' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

I cannot understand what is happening here. Could someone please tell me, how could I return a structure from `server_create` of type `my_server_t*`.

Comment: You try to cast a struct to a pointer; this is not possible. Try `return (my_server_t*)&server_t;`

Comment: Apart from that, your naming is awful. You should not use `server_t` as a struct instance, the `_t` suffix is used for _types_

Comment: As a third issue, you should not return a pointer to local storage, that will invalidate after leaving the function. So while it is syntactically correct, it will invoke UB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate about what this function should do, but you seem to want to allocate a new `my_server_t` structure and return it. Instead, you are defining a new structure inside your function and returning it, which is invalid.

What you want is probably this:

```
my_server_t *server_create(void) {
    my_server_t *srv = malloc(sizeof my_server_t);
    if (srv == NULL)
        return NULL; // Failed to allocate memory.

    srv->port = /* some default value */;
    srv->pending_connections_allowed = /* some default value */;

    return srv;
}
```

You could also pass field values as arguments, if you want:

```
my_server_t *server_create_with_values(unsigned short port, int pending) {
    my_server_t *srv = malloc(sizeof my_server_t);
    if (srv == NULL)
        return NULL; // Failed to allocate memory.

    srv->port = port;
    srv->pending_connections_allowed = pending;

    return srv;
}
```

Later in your code you can then use the function:

```
my_server_t *foo = server_create();
// or
my_server_t *foo = server_create_with_values(1337, 0);
```

Also, do not forget to free the allocated memory when it is no longer needed:

```
free(foo);
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'my_server_t' (aka 'struct my_server_t')`

Comment: @Amanda that's a whole different problem. It means that the compiler does not see any definition for `struct my_server_t`. You should define that first.